# Sans serif fonts for section titles in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, sectioning, context, sans-serif

In LaTeX, some document classes specify sans serif fonts for chapter and section titles, and serif fonts for the main text of a document. what is the proper way to achieve this in ConTeXt? I have code like this, to specify my fonts:

```
\starttypescript[serif][minionpro]
    \definefontsynonym[Serif][name:minionpro]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript[minionpro]
    \definetypeface[minionpro][rm][serif][minionpro][default]
\stoptypescript

\setupbodyfont[minionpro, 12pt]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\setuphead[chapter][style={\ssc}]
\setuphead[section][style={\ssb}]
```

ConTeXt uses `\ss` to denote `sans-serif`, and the suffixes `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` refer to font size. See [font switching](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Font_Switching) on the context wiki for more details.

Comment: Just wanted to note that the `e` suffix doesn't work (anymore), at least right now on my ConTeXt installation (2019-06-04).